# How to open Dialog Box in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-alertdialog

I am selecting an image from gallery with the Intent method of android.

Now after selecting the image,
i want to ask user in a dialog box where he has to select Yes or No.

How do i do that?

Code:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
            {
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
```

I want to open dialog here on

> onActivityResult

, after selecting the image.

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: i have updated my question @IntelliJAmiya

Answer (score 1):

here is how to make dialog box

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setTitle("Delete entry")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")

    // Specifying a listener allows you to take an action before dismissing the dialog.
    // The dialog is automatically dismissed when a dialog button is clicked.
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // Continue with delete operation
        }
     })

    // A null listener allows the button to dismiss the dialog and take no further action.
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .show();
```